# Facebook Iframe styling

Tags: facebook, iframe, styling

I am unable to apply the z-index styling for the facebook likebutton which i have on my page.

ex: http://jsbin.com/ogupen/4/edit

Want the styling to be applied to #LikePluginPagelet

```
$("#LikePluginPagelet").contents().find("a").css("z-index","-999999");
```

Comment: Why do you want to hack the facebook plugin?

Comment: the fb like button is overlapping some content on my page... so i want to make the chages

Answer (score 0):

Playing with the plugins is not a good way to go since you have absolutely no control on how they are implemented, and so tomorrow facebook can decide to change something, they can suddenly change "LikePluginPagelet" to "LikePlugin" and then your code will have no effect.

True, you can try to stay up to date with current changes facebook are making, but those type of things are not reported by them in the roadmap for example, and so it will make things harder for you.

What you can do however is to control the element which contains the fb plugin, since it's in your page and you can do what ever you want with it.
If "the fb like button is overlapping some content on my page" then just make sure that the element that contains the fb like button has the right z-index, instead of trying to hack the like button itself.